# Samsung Galaxy S21 with Odin3 did not root or flash for some reason

Tags: samsung, rooting, odin, magisk, samsung-galaxy-s-21

I just flashed my Samsung Galaxy S21 with Odin3 and it said "PASS!" and then it reset and rebooted. But it did not say "The phone is not running Samsung's official software" or whatever.

It looks normal. DOES NOT look like it has been rooted and no suspicious files either. I did everything,  flashing with Magisk and Odin3 but still nothing. No sign and works fine.

Should I just try again, or do you guys have any answer to this?